# Continuity of a certain vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, physics

Let us define $$\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{x}):=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_)}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3$$where $(y_1,y_2,y_3)=\boldsymbol{y}$, where $\rho:D\subset\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded piecewise continuous function, $k$ a positive constant and $D\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded. If $k$ is Coulomb's constant, we can consider $\boldsymbol{E}$ as an expression of the electrical field in $\boldsymbol{x}$ generated by the charge having density $\rho$ on $D$.

I would like to prove that, under these assumptions, $\boldsymbol{E}:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is continuous. Such function has been proved to be defined on all $\mathbb{R}^3$ [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213659/gausss-law-if-the-integral-defining-boldsymbole-diverges/213681#213681) (at the same link there is a proof, in the *addendum* to the answer, that under such assumptions $\boldsymbol{E}\in C(\mathbb{R}^3)$, but I have to follow another path because I really do not understand the calculations and inequalities in that addendum).

I have included a trial of proof by me, hoping that somebody more mathematically cultivated can correct my trial, confirm its (improbable) correctness or provide an alternative answer (using tools that I can understand - of course - such as multivariate calculus, while I have no knowledge of Lebesgue integration in $\mathbb{R}^3$). I thank any answerer very much.

---

***Proof (trial of)***: Let us define$$\boldsymbol{E}_n(\boldsymbol{x}):=\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3$$It can be easily shown, by using polar coordinates around $\boldsymbol{x}$, that the sequence $\{\boldsymbol{E}_n\}$ uniformly converges to $\boldsymbol{E}$ if $\lim_{n}\varepsilon_n=0$. Morever, the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is a continuous function, which implies that, if $\boldsymbol{E}_n$
 is continuous for any $n$ and $\varepsilon_n\to 0$, then $\boldsymbol{E}\in C(\mathbb{R}^3)$. To prove that $\boldsymbol{E}_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^3$, let us introduce the function $$\boldsymbol{F}_{n,\boldsymbol{x}_0}(\boldsymbol{x}):=\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3$$defined on $B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n/2)$, where $\boldsymbol{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a given point. Let us notice the domain of integration, different in general from that of $\boldsymbol{E}_n$, although $\boldsymbol{E}_n(\boldsymbol{x}_0)=\boldsymbol{F}_{n,\boldsymbol{x}_0}(\boldsymbol{x}_0)$. The function $\boldsymbol{f}:\overline{B\left(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\frac{\varepsilon_n}{2}\right)}\times\overline{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, where the over line means closure, defined by $\boldsymbol{f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})}:=\frac{\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}$ can be straightforwardly proved to be continuous (if I am not wrong) and therefore uniformly continuous on its compact domain. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta$ such that, if $\|(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})-(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\boldsymbol{y})\|<\delta$, then $$\|\boldsymbol{F}_{n,\boldsymbol{x}_0}(\boldsymbol{x})-\boldsymbol{E}_n(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\|\leq k\sup_{D}|\rho|\int_{D\setminus  B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}\left\|\frac{\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}
- \frac{\boldsymbol{x}_0-\boldsymbol{y}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}_0-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}
\right\|\,\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3$$ $$\leq k\sup_{D}|\rho|\,\varepsilon\,\mu(D\setminus  B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))$$ where $\mu$ is volume.

Moreover, I would say that, if we can prove that, as $\boldsymbol{x}\to \boldsymbol{x}_0$, $\boldsymbol{E}_n(\boldsymbol{x})$ approaches  $\boldsymbol{F}_{n,\boldsymbol{x}_0}(\boldsymbol{x})$, we have proved that $\boldsymbol{E}_n$ is continuous in the arbitrarily chosen point $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, and I would think that we can prove that by using the fact that $\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}$ $=\int_{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}-\int_{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}$ we can write, for $\boldsymbol{x}\in B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\delta)$, $\delta\le\varepsilon_n/2$, $$\left\|\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3-\int_{D\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3\right\|$$ $$=\Bigg\| \int_\limits{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}^{} \frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3-\int_\limits{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}^{}\frac{k\rho(\boldsymbol{y})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})}{\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\|^{3}}\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3 \Bigg\|$$$$\le\int_\limits{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n)}^{} \frac{k\sup|\rho|}{\varepsilon_n^2}\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3+\int_\limits{(D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n)}^{}\frac{k\sup|\rho|}{(\varepsilon_n-\delta)^2}\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2\text{d}y_3 $$$$\le k\sup|\rho|\left(\frac{\mu((D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n))}{\varepsilon_n^2}+\frac{\mu((D\cap B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon_n))\setminus B(\boldsymbol{x}_0,\varepsilon_n))}{(\varepsilon_n -\delta)^2}\right)$$where both volumes $\mu$ approaches 0 as $\delta\to 0$. Which completes my proof.

Comment: Is $D$ a bounded set?

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for your interest: yes, I intended it to be bounded, and have edited the post to stress that.

Comment: Congratulations on your self study. How far have you gone in analysis? Have you learned any measure theory?

Comment: @zhw. Honoured by your comment: thank you. I know a very, vey little bit: what is explained in Kolmogorov-Fomin's Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа (≈≈Introductory Real Analysis) only.

Comment: Knowing that book is not a very very little. It's kind of a classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second answer (no measure theory): Let $f$ be a nice bounded function on $D$ (like $k\rho$). For suitable $g,$ define $Tg(x) = \int_D f(y)g(x-y)\,dy, x \in \mathbb {R}^3.$ One suitable $g$ is any $g\in C_c$ (where $C_c$ is the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb {R}^3$ with compact support). Other examples are $g(y) = y_k/|y|^3.$ These are the only examples we need worry about.

Claim 1: If $g \in C_c,$ then $Tg$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R}^3.$ This follows straightforwardly from the uniform continuity of $g$ on $\mathbb {R}^3,$ the boundedness of $f,$ and the boundedness of $D.$

Now each $g(y)=y_k/|y|^3$ is not in $C_c,$ but we'll take care of that. For small $\epsilon > 0$ and large $R> 0,$ define $\phi_{\epsilon,R}$ on $[0,\infty)$ in the following way: Join the points $(0,0),(\epsilon,0), (2\epsilon, 1), (R,1), (R+\epsilon,0)$ with straight line segments. That is the graph of $\phi_{\epsilon,R}$ on $[0, R+\epsilon].$ Define $\phi_{\epsilon,R} = 0$ on $(R+\epsilon,\infty).$ (It's good to draw a picture.) Note that each $g(y)\phi_{\epsilon,R}(|y|)\in C_c.$

Claim 2: Let $g(y) = y_k/|y|^3,$ and suppose $R>0.$ Then

$$\int_{B(0,R)} |g(y)-\phi_{\epsilon,R}(|y|)g(y)|\, dy < 12\pi\epsilon.$$

Proof: This comes right out of integrating in polar coordinates in $\mathbb {R}^3.$

So here's how we finish. Let $g$ be as in claim 2. We have $D \subset B(0,r)$ for some $r.$ Fix $a.$ Let $R = 1+|a|+r.$ Set $h(y) = g(y)\phi_{\epsilon,R}(|y|).$ Then for $x \in B(a,1),$

$$|Tg(x) - Tg(a)| \le |Tg(x) - Th(x)| + |Th(x) - Th(a)| + |Th(a) - Tg(a)|.$$

Now recall $|f|$ is bounded by some $M$ on $D.$ So

$$|Tg(x) - Th(x)|\le M\int_D |g(x-y) - h(x-y)|\,dy = M\int_{-D+x} |g(y) - h(y)|\,dy$$ $$  \le M\int_{B(0,R)}|g-h| \le M\cdot 12\pi\epsilon,$$

where we have used the fact that $-D+x\subset B(0,R).$ Same for $|Th(a) - Tg(a)|.$ Thus

$$\limsup_{x\to a}|Tg(x) - Tg(a)| \le M\cdot12\pi\epsilon + 0 + M\cdot 12\pi\epsilon.$$

We have used claim 1 to get that $0$ in the middle. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the $\limsup$ is $0,$ giving us the result.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your proof a bit and it seems to me you have the right ideas. But a little measure theory can make life easier.

Well known result: If $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb {R}^3), g \in L^1(\mathbb {R}^3),$ then

$$\tag 1 f\ast g (x) = \int_{\mathbb {R}^3} f(y)g(x-y)\,dy$$

is continuous on $\mathbb {R}^3.$ (And in fact $f\ast g (x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty.$)

How would this apply to your situation? I'm thinking of $f=k\rho$ in $D,$ $f=0$ elsewhere, and $g(y) = y_k/|y|^3,k=1,2,3.$ There's a problem however: $g\not \in L^1(\mathbb {R}^3)$ because of the behavior of $g(y)$ for $|y|$ large.

Let's dispense with this problem. Let $g(y) = y_1/|y|^3$ for example. We have $D\subset B(0,R)$ for some $R>0.$ Fix $a;$ we will prove the desired continuity for $x \in B(a,1).$ Verify that if $x\in B(a,1),y\in D,$ then $|x-y| \le |a| + 1 + R.$ If we define $h = g\chi_{B(0,|a| + 1 + R)},$ then $h(x-y) = g(x-y)$ for $x\in B(a,1),y\in D.$ This tells us

$$\int_{\mathbb {R}^3} f(y)g(x-y)\,dy = \int_{D} f(y)g(x-y)\,dy =\int_{D} f(y)h(x-y)\,dy = \int_{\mathbb {R}^3} f(y)h(x-y)\,dy$$

for $x \in B(a,1).$ Because $h \in L^1(\mathbb {R}^3),$ $(1)$ shows the last integral is continuous everywhere, hence the second integral is continuous for $x\in B(a,1)$as promised.

So how do you get $(1)?$ You prove it first for continuous $g$ with compact support; here it follows from the uniform continuity of $g.$ Then you use the fact that if $g\in L^1(\mathbb {R^3})$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then there exists a continuous $h$ with compact support such that

$$\tag 2 \int_{\mathbb {R}^3} |g(y) - h(y)|\,dy < \epsilon.$$

So you approximate $g$ by such an $h$ and take an appropriate $\limsup$ to get $(1).$

If I've used some measure theory results you haven't seen, note that in your problem you have only the functions $g(y) = y_k/|y|^3$ to worry about, so approximating as in $(2)$ is pretty simple. I think you could fashion a proof using these ideas, probably avoiding measure theory altogether.

Comment: I must admit that I haven't got the tools to understand it (which means knowing proofs of the results that are necessary to prove it, according to my definition of understanding) because, for ex., I've never seen even a proof that the set of continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (and Kolmogorov-Fomin's doesn't even deal with Lebesgue summability in $\mathbb{R}^3$: the only examples of measure spaces dealt with in discussing Lebesgue integrals are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, although I suspect that Riemann integrability always implies Lebesgue integrability).

Comment: Hi, I don't have the time or patience to read throught your proof with the requisite care to confirm it. (There's quite a bit of complicated notation there!)  What I wanted to do here is come up with a simpler and cleaner - and more general - approach. I think this can be done without measure theory and I may just write that up. (I'm not worried about the bounty!)

Comment: I'll try to clear that up for you soon, today or tomorrow.